# how to compress or reduce size of gif file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, resize, compression, gif

I made gif file with flutter_video_compress package ( its compress and make gif too )
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_video_compress

but there is one problem
gif size is too big.
i will put the gif file into firebase storage.
right now.. it's nothing to worry about but it will be a problem sooner or later I guess.

i searched packages for it
but there is no compress or resize package for gif file.

found one image compress package
but there is no description about gif

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress

is there a way to solve this??

Comment: Just ran into the same today, did you find anything ? I have tested flutter_image_compress  it doesn't work on GIF files unfortunately